# Dust js partials / child templaes output undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, templates, dust.js, nw.js

I'm using nwjs and dust.js. Parent templates work as expected, but if I try to load a child (partial) template the output is undefined. Am I missing something to get child/partial templates working? Thanks.

```
<div id="output"></div>

<script>
   const  dust = require('dustjs-helpers'); 
</script>
<!-- Because I can't figure out why require(./dist/templates) errors dust undefined. -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="./dist/templates.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
let templateName = 'src/templates/anotherTemplate',
    data = {heading: "This is a heading", article: "Blah blah blah."};

dust.render(templateName, data, (err, out) => {
    console.log(out);
    document.getElementById('output').innerHTML = out;
}); 
</script>
```

Templates:

someTemplate.dust: (parent)

```
<h1>{heading}</h1>
<p>{article}</p>
{+someBlock/}
```

anotherTemplate.dust: (child/partial)

```
{>someTemplate/}
{<someBlock}
    My custom block content.
{/someBlock}
```

Compiled templates: 
(compiled with dustc - ./node_modules/dustjs-linkedin/bin/dustc ./src/templates/*.dust -o ./dist/templates.js)

```
(function(dust){dust.register("src\/templates\/anotherTemplate",body_0);var blocks={"someBlock":body_1};function body_0(chk,ctx){ctx=ctx.shiftBlocks(blocks);return chk.p("someTemplate",ctx,ctx,{});}body_0.__dustBody=!0;function body_1(chk,ctx){ctx=ctx.shiftBlocks(blocks);return chk.w("My custom block content.");}body_1.__dustBody=!0;return body_0}(dust));
(function(dust){dust.register("src\/templates\/someTemplate",body_0);function body_0(chk,ctx){return chk.w("<h1>").f(ctx.get(["heading"], false),ctx,"h").w("</h1><p>").f(ctx.get(["article"], false),ctx,"h").w("</p>").b(ctx.getBlock("someBlock"),ctx,{},{});}body_0.__dustBody=!0;return body_0}(dust));
```

Comment: Since it isn't the point of this question, leaving a comment-- if you want to require() your Dust templates, compile them as CommonJS modules with `--cjs` (but then you have to require each template separately): http://www.dustjs.com/guides/rendering/#node-load-precompiled-templates

Comment: CommonJS example: https://github.com/linkedin/dustjs/tree/master/examples/commonjs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're including `{>someTemplate/}`, but you've registered the template with a different name: `src/templates/someTemplate`.

If you want Dust to register your templates without the `src/templates` prefix, [pass the `--pwd` parameter to dustc](http://www.dustjs.com/docs/dustc-api/#pwd):

```
./node_modules/dustjs-linkedin/bin/dustc ./src/templates/*.dust -o ./dist/templates.js --pwd=src/templates
```

Comment: I tried {>"src/templates/someTemplate"/} and using --pwd=src/templates (separately) to the same result the base template loads and the child is still undefined.

Comment: NM had to clear the dust cache. Thanks for the help.

Comment: During development you might want to set `dust.config.cache` to `false` if your process is long-lived (Express, NW, etc)